# show options dropdown only on click in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code as shown below

```
<label>Dropdown :</label>
<select multiple="multiple" id="dropdown">
<option selected="selected" value="">Please Select</option>
    <option id="1">Opt 1  </option>
    <option id="2">Opt 2  </option>
    <option id="3">Opt 3  </option>
    <option id="4">Opt 4  </option>
</select>
```

In JS

```
$('option').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);
    var values = $('#dropdown').val();
    alert(values);
    return false;
});
```

Check out a sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bbjk/89g6t610/)

This produce an output with the dropdown already expanded. But i want the dropdown to expand only on click, allow to select multiple options and display all selected values in the dropdown with comma separated values.

How to do this?.

```js
$('option').mousedown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('selected', $(this).prop('selected') ? false : true);
    var values = $('#dropdown').val();
    alert(values);
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Dropdown :</label>
<select multiple="multiple" id="dropdown">
<option selected="selected" value="">Please Select</option>
    <option id="1">Opt 1  </option>
    <option id="2">Opt 2  </option>
    <option id="3">Opt 3  </option>
    <option id="4">Opt 4  </option>
</select>
```

EDIT: I found @bRIMOs and  @AdhershMNair answers are very helpful. They have used different plugin to achieve same criteria with different UI. Which i found very helpful and learn more from them because of their patience and willingness.

Comment: You may use bootstrap mutiselect js. https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Ekd8P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Select2](https://select2.github.io/)

```js
$(function(){
   $("#dropdown2").select2({
    "language": {
         "noResults": function(){
             return "Please select";
         }
     }
  });
  
  $("#dropdown").select2({
    "language": {
         "noResults": function(){
             return "Please select";
         }
     }
  });
  
  $("#dropdown").on("select2:select",function(e){
    var values = $(this).select2("val");
    if(values.indexOf("Clear All")!=-1)
       $(this).select2("val","All");
    else
    alert(values.join(","));
  });
  $("#dropdown").on("select2:unselect",function(e){
    var values = $(this).select2("val");
    if(values) alert(values.join(","));
  })
  
  $("#dropdown").on("change",function(e){
    var values = $(this).select2("val");
    if(values) console.log("Using Change event :",values.join(","));
  })
});
```

```css
#dropdown ,#dropdown2 {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<label>Dropdown :</label>
<select multiple="multiple" id="dropdown">
    <option>Clear All</option>
    <option id="1">Opt 1  </option>
    <option id="2">Opt 2  </option>
    <option id="3">Opt 3  </option>
    <option id="4">Opt 4  </option>
</select>
<br><br>
<label>Dropdown<br> with no data :</label>
<select multiple="multiple" id="dropdown2">
    
</select>
```

Comment: i think i am using bootstrap v3.2, so it gives me  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).live is not a function

Comment: have you added select2.js and select2.css after jquery in your code ?

Comment: yes, i have used, but error shows here  $("#dropdown").live("change", function() {  
 }); . because here onchange i need to apply logic

Comment: please follow my answer : use `.on("select2:select")` event or `.on("change")` event , and get values using  `$(this).select2("val");`

Comment: If there is no data onclick i get no results found. Instead this i need to hide this or rename to please select

Comment: I did not understand ! what you want exactely ?

Comment: i mean remove options in select, then click on dropdown then u get "No results found". Instead of this i need to display "Please select"

Comment: yes. Last one, i want to add clear all option as first option in select. If i select that, previous all selected options should be cleared.

Comment: See the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [select2](https://select2.github.io/) plugin. Extremely helpful in such cases and highly configurable.

```js
$('select').select2({
  placeholder: "Select an option",
  allowClear: true
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<label>Dropdown :</label>
<select id="dropdown" multiple="multiple" style="width: 150px">
    <option id="1">Opt 1  </option>
    <option id="2">Opt 2  </option>
    <option id="3">Opt 3  </option>
    <option id="4">Opt 4  </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It may meet your requirement. But you need to link these libraries.

[Bootstrap Multiselect Documentation.](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/)

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />



    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dropdown').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        nonSelectedText: 'Please Select',
         selectAllText: 'Please Select'
    });
});
    </script>
    <label>Dropdown :</label>
    <select multiple="multiple" id="dropdown">
        <option id="1">Opt 1  </option>
        <option id="2">Opt 2  </option>
        <option id="3">Opt 3  </option>
        <option id="4">Opt 4  </option>
    </select>
<style type="text/css">
 .multiselect-container *{
  outline: none !important;
 }
 .multiselect-container>li>a>label>input[type=checkbox] {
     visibility: hidden;
 }

 .multiselect-container>li>a>label {
     padding: 5px;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Here i dont want to show checkbox and select all option, and on select of Please select other options previously selected must be cleared.

Comment: You May Use CSS to hide the radio box.

Comment: Code Updated with your requirement

Comment: here if i select on please select, it gets all option selected on first click and deselect all option on second click. i want to show all values selcted to be shown with commas, but here after three option selcted it shows number of options selected.

Comment: It can be change in javascript by increasing limit. but this will overflow the selectbox.

Comment: Here if i select 'Please select' it selects and deselects alternately. I want it to deselect on choosing 'Please select'. and can you say in which js file i need to increase limit. because when i search i find page full of code.

Comment: To Increase what linit?

Comment: If options are selected more than 3, it displays number of options selected. But i need to show all text values as many are selected.